# Terraform application load balancer argument is not expected here

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-elb

I currently work on an AWS architecture that looks like this :
NLB -> ALB -> API Gateway -> Lambda

When I deploy my architecture, the **Preserve host header** attribute of the ALB is set to false. I want it set to true.

As from Terraform doc https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb :

- `preserve_host_header` - (Optional) Indicates whether the Application Load Balancer should preserve the Host header in the HTTP request and send it to the target without any change. Defaults to false.

Here is my Application Load Balancer configuration :

```
resource "aws_lb" "alb_to_api_gateway" {
      name               = "prd-alb-toapigw"
      internal           = true
      load_balancer_type = "application"
      security_groups = [var.default_SG]
      subnets    = [var.subnet_backend_a, var.subnet_backend_b]
    
      preserve_host_header = true
    
      access_logs {
        bucket  = aws_s3_bucket.elb_logs.id
        prefix  = "ALB"
        enabled = true
      }
    
      depends_on = [
       aws_s3_bucket_policy.policy_alb
      ]
    }
```

This configuration worked perfectly until I added the preserve_host_header argument which creates this error :

```
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on elb.tf line 12, in resource "aws_lb" "alb_to_api_gateway":
│   12:   preserve_host_header = true
│ 
│ An argument named "preserve_host_header" is not expected here.
```

I use Terraform v1.3.9 on linux_amd64

provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/archive v2.2.0

provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.15.1

aws-cli/2.11.0 Python/3.11.2 Linux/5.4.0-1045-aws exe/x86_64.ubuntu.20 prompt/off

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `preserve_host_header` argument was added in [version 4.25.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#4250-august--4-2022) of the AWS provider, and you would therefore need to update the provider from 4.15.1 to >= 4.25.0.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Can you tell me how did you find which version I needed from the attribute ? Just so I can look it up myself next time.

Comment: @Achi Note the link in the answer for that information.